# When is the Poincare-polynomial of an element in the Grothendieck ring the actual Poincare polynomial of a representative?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

There is a well-defined map
$$P:K(Var)\to \mathbb{Z}[t]$$
which sends smooth projective varieties to their Poincare polynomial. This is in fact enough to define $P$ on all elements of $K(Var)$.

I wonder if there are any sufficient conditions under which $P([X])$ is the Poincare polynomial of $X$, other then $X$ being smooth projective?

Comment: What do you mean by the Poincaré polynomial of $X$ in this setting?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of mixed Hodge theory you have
$$ P(X) = \sum_k \dim(\mathrm{Gr}^W_k H^\ast_c(X)) \cdot t^k$$
where $H^\ast_c(X)$ is the direct sum of all the (rational) cohomology groups of $X$ with compact support. So the most natural condition on $X$ which implies that its Poincaré polynomial equals $P(X)$, is that $X$ is compact and that all its cohomology groups are pure. In particular "projective" can be weakened to "proper", and "smooth" can be weakened to "rational homology manifold", but there are more examples, e.g. the projective cone over a smooth projective curve.